# Why pod install changing the Podfile and xcode workspace from original?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cocoapods

In my xcode project, there are few pods installed, and after I commit the project, when I pull from another device, the pod install of the same pod file modifying the Xcode project work-space and pod file itself. What is the reason? Shouldn't it supposed to have the exact same pod installation?

Comment: This is a good question. I also wonder about that.

Comment: and would it be better if i commit pod directory itself? and is pod directory untracked in git?

Answer (score 1):

`pod install` resolves the dependencies based on `Podfile`.
These dependencies are listed in `Podfile.lock`. If you do not have this file (it was not added to source control) your installation may not be the same.

The other reason might be different version of `cocoapods` on different machines.

So you should commit `Podfile.lock` if you do not commit `Pods/` directory.

Comment: Yes. I'm committing Podfile.lock . And you may be right about cocoapods version. I'll check if there is any difference.